# Can't add Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc) on Network Manager (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: network-manager, 22.04, vpnc

After installing `vpnc`, `network-manager-vpnc` and `network-manager-vpnc-gnome`, the "Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc)" option appears on the "Add VPN" menu in network manager as intended. The problem I'm having is that, despite having filled all necessary fields (so, gateway, user/group name/password), the "Add" button stays greyed out. It does seem to be a bug, since if I fill the gateway and the user name fields, the button will go green **if I type only one character in the group name field** (it doesn't save, however).

Comment: Same here. It was working fine with those packages on 20.04.

Comment: I tried the solution of daltux, but that didn't work for me. I use Ubuntu 22.04, a fresh installation and I use network-manager-vpnc and the gnome GUI version 1.2.8-2
The solution of Manuel Uberti does work though. It changes my public IP nr and I get a tunnel to the server, but I cant access anything on the network I am connecting to. I may try another VPN clients, like softether-vpnclient that is in the repositories.

Comment: Mayby this can help?
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701185
Have some VPN problem on 22.04, when 20.04 works all fine.

Comment: Same here. It was working fine with for me with these packages on 18.04 and 20.04.
it doesn´t work via terminal with vpnc-connect or network

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The form validation seems buggy and there is a required field ("interface name") which was not required before. It is in the "Advanced" window.

There is a GUI workaround. Instead of editing the connection with the main Gnome Settings application, you have to do the following:

1. Launch Advanced Network Configuration (or run `nm-connection-editor` from terminal)
2. Click the "+" (Add a new connection), choose "Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc)", click "Create..."
3. Fill all the fields
4. Click the "Advanced..." button
5. Fill "Tunnel interface name" with `tun0`
6. Click "Apply"
7. The Save button will still be disabled. Click "Advanced..." again and "Apply", or try ticking "Use hybrid authentication" and then tick it again.
8. Finally, you will be able to "Save"!

This is tested on Ubuntu 22.04, Lubuntu 22.04, Pop!_OS 22.04, all with `network-manager-vpnc-gnome` version 1.2.8-2.

Bug reports on this issue already open in each project:

- [GNOME](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-vpnc/-/issues/8)
- [NetworkManager](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/982)
- [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1968588)

Comment: Thank you for this, I can confirm it works.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04: for me after point 7 the Add button is still disabled

Comment: @Mark Please try again with Advanced Network Configuration. The standard settings unfortunately really never enables the Add button.

Comment: `sudo nm-connection-editor` helped me out with an Anyconnect server.

Comment: Doesn't work for login+password authentication method. "Save" button is still disabled.

Comment: I confirm the problem Dmitry Sazonov reported. When using the login and password authentication method, the trick of daltux unfortunately does not work.

Comment: This worked for me ONLY when I ran `nm-connection-editor` from the terminal. It did NOT work when I went to the network configuration in the settings gui.

Comment: Btw, on 22.04, if you type something in "Group name", than delete/backspace any character, you won't be able to "Save"

Comment: Works on 22.04.1.  Note that you you can't find the vpn configuration using the standard UI

Answer (score 6):

To temporarily work around this issue, I am using the command line approach for now by connecting to the VPN I need through the `vpnc` command.

I followed the instructions from [Using vpnc as a Command Line VPN Client](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/using-vpnc-as-a-command-line-vpn-client), so basically this is what I did (as root user):

- I copied `/etc/vpnc/default.conf` to `/etc/vpnc/myvpn.conf`
- I filled `/etc/vpnc/myvpn.conf` with the details of my VPN:

```
IPSec gateway mygateway
IPSec ID mygroupid
IPSec secret mygrouppassword
IKE Authmode psk
Xauth username myuser
Xauth password mypass
```

- Then, as root, `vpnc myvpn.conf` (or as normal user: `sudo vpcn myvpn.conf`)
- To disconnect `vpnc-disconnect` as root (or as normal user: `sudo vpnc-disconnect`)

It's not as handy as clicking through the UI, but at least it's working.